# SQL Server find consecutive failure records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I've look at so many other questions and nothing quite fits my question or gets me the answer I need, maybe I'm just slow today :(

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    [InstructionId] INT,
    [InstructionDetailId] INT,
    [Sequence] INT,
    [Status] INT
 ) 
 INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,111,1, 2
 INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,112,2,2
 INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,113,3,4
 INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,114,4,4
 INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,115,5,2
 INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,116,6,4
 INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,117,7,2
 INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,118,8,4
 INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,119,9,4
 INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,120,10,2
 INSERT INTO @t SELECT 222,121,11,2
```

I need to find for which InstructionDetailId's there are consecutive failures (Status = 4) by using the [Sequence] field for checking the order to determine if they are consecutive. So for the above InstructionDetailId 113 and 114 would be consecutive failures as their [Sequence] is 3 & 4, same for InstructionDetailId 118 and 119 would be consecutive failures. I've tried so many row number variation and cte's and I can't quite crack it :( This is for SQL Server 2008 R2 by the way.

Expected output:

```
InstructionId   InstructionDetailId Sequence    Status
222                            113       3           4
222                            114       4           4
222                            118       8           4
222                            119       9           4
```

Thanx all!

Comment: post the expected output

Comment: When you looked at those questions, did you try anything yourself? What was the code you used to try and get the results you wanted, and why weren't they right?

Comment: @Larnu yeah as I mentioned above, I've tried so many diff cte's and row number variations and not quite getting it

Comment: @jjay225 then post that code so we can see where you went wrong, and help you correct it.

Comment: The above resultset can be arrived at with just a WHERE clause no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `APPLY` :

```
select t.*
from @t t outer apply
     ( select top (1) t1.*
       from @t t1
       where t1.InstructionId = t.InstructionId and
             t1.Sequence < t.Sequence
       order by t1.Sequence desc
     ) t1 outer apply
     ( select top (1) t2.*
       from @t t2
       where t2.InstructionId = t.InstructionId and
             t2.Sequence > t.Sequence
       order by t2.Sequence 
     ) t2
where t.status = 4 and (t.status = t1.status or t.status = t2.status);
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the simplest method is to use `lag()` and `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(t.status) over (partition by t.InstructionId order by t.sequence) as prev_status,
             lead(t.status) over (partition by t.InstructionId order by t.sequence) as next_status
      from @t t
     ) t
where status = prev_status or status = next_status;
```

Comment: Thanx Gordon but I forgot to add that I need it for SQL Server 2008, just edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like...

```
    select t1.InstructionID,
           t1.InstructionDetailID,
           t1.Sequence,
           t1.Status,
      from @t t1
     inner join @t t2 on t1.InstructionID = t2.InstructionID
                     and t1.Sequence = (t2.Sequence - 1)
                     and t1.Status = t2.Status
                     and t1.Status = 4
```